# How to configure docker registry always up and running when configured with redis?

Tags: redis, docker, docker-registry

I have configured docker registry with Redis. Redis is acting as source and docker registry is the receiver. I would like to configure it in such a way so that:

1. Docker registry is always up and running.
2. If I use `restart=always` as parameter for docker registry, how do I ensure that Redis is up and running before docker registry does?
3. It would be great if the docker image could be registered in such a way that it could not be deleted accidentally.

How to do that?